# What are the origins of the idiom "dying to..."?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Where did the expression "dying to..." come from?

e.g.

> I'm dying to meet you.

Comment: Good question.  It may also be worth answering the etymology of the similar idiom, 'dying for...' which I suspect is similar.

Comment: Please show some background research.

Comment: A joke my father used to tell (too many times) whenever we drove past a cemetery: "*Why do they put fences around graveyards? — Because so many people are dying to get in.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only speculate, but this simple hyperbole was probably generated many times for the same reasons:

- *I would die to meet you. => I am **dying to** meet you.*

as Jez mentions similar transformation happened in *'dying for...'*

- *I would die to have some strawberries. => I am **dying for** some strawberries.*

[Dying to](http://dictionaries.cambridge.org/define.asp?key=die%2a1%200&dict=A) is listed in CDO as

> To be dying to do something, or for something, is to be eager to do or to have it.

Etymology might be related to several paths:

- *dying wish* - considered a wish that should be granted, so construct such as: "*I want to meet you and I want it so much as if it was a dying wish. I am dying to see you!*", though far fetched might actually be related
- suffering because you lack something (food, love, etc..); for example you could actually and literally be dying for some food, so such use is obviously justified. From this a hyperbole can be applied to any object of desire or need.
- I believe that it is quite natural to express strong desire by comparing it with one's own well being; to the question of "*How much do you want it/that?*", there is a very natural answer that means *completely* and that is to say "*I would give my life to have it.*"

Answer (score 0):

I agree on the whole with Unreason's answer. I think the origin of the term is as a hyperbole of the basic statement "I am dying for [lack of/want of] something", which in turn implies a need that, unmet, is causing physical suffering and may literally result in death, as in Unreason's example of food.

I think that the similar, probably hyperbolic sentence "I would die for something" actually has a different origin than "I am dying for something".

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I can very easily believe the expression to have its origins in a perfectly literal expression like, "The patient is dying for lack of a transfusion," or "the children are slowly dying for lack of adequate nutrition."